# Find the range of the function : $\frac{1}{\pi}(\sin^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}x) + \frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Problem : Find the range of the function : $\frac{1}{\pi}(\sin^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}x) + \frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+5}$

My approach :

Let $g(x) = (\sin^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}x)$  and $h(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+5}$

and domain of $g(x)$ is $[-1,1]$

$\therefore$ maximum value of $g(x)$ is $g(1) = \frac{3}{4}$

and minimum value of $g(x)$ is at $g(-1) = -\frac{3}{4}$

Now how to find the maximum minimum value of $h(x) $

Let $h(x)=y=\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+5}$

$\therefore y(x^2+2x+5)=x+1$

$\Rightarrow x^2y +x(2y-1)+5y-1=0$ .......(i)

Can we find the range of $h(x)$ using (i) Please guide on this thanks.. or there is any other alternative method using concept of maxima minima i.e. using differentiation. Thanks.